# The program goes to newline and nothing is output in the screen

Tags: c++

I am working on a problem that is to capitalize the first character of each sentence in the string. For example, if the string argument is "hello. my name is Joe. what is your name?" and the program would return 'Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?" My question why after I inputted the string that I wanted to capitalize and pressed enter, the program goes to newline and nothing is output in the screen.

Here is my code:

```
//Sentence Capitalizer
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char argument[1024];
  cout<<"Please enter a c string as an agrument and I will capitalizes the first character of each sentence in string: ";
  cin.getline(argument, 1024);
  argument[0] = toupper(argument[0]);
  int i = 0;
  while (argument[i+2] != '\0')
  {
      if (argument[i] == '.')
      {
          argument[i+2] = toupper(argument[i+2]); 
      }
      i++;
  }
  cout<<argument[0]<<endl;
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please learn to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: I ran the code in cpp.sh and there isn't any warning.

Comment: use puts(argument) to print argument in the last statement. You'll have to include stdio.h to use puts() .

Comment: `cpp.sh` is probably not a standard thing. And you need to use your debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Your bug lies in

```
cout<<argument[i]<<endl;
```

You have updated `i` to a position possibly near `'\0'` and then trying to print it.

## Fix

After you come out of the loop print only `argument`. Or if you want to print each sentence in separate line, memorize the index from which you should print till `i`.

Also `return 0` inside `while` body appears incorrect. I think you meant to place it after `while` block.

Moreover from [this comment of Paolo M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604798/the-program-goes-to-newline-and-nothing-is-output-in-the-screen/31604846#comment51160199_31604846), using semicolon after `while` and `if` is something that you don't intend.

[Live example after correction](http://ideone.com/ulIJUL)

Comment: Semicolons at the end of while and if statements don't help, also :)